# Unreal engine android game uploaded to google play, some people get this error

Tags: android, unreal-engine4, google-developers-console

I uploaded a game to google play, and some people keep getting this crash. I can't understand where is the problem. If someone has a solution, please tell me

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlx.a (Unknown Source:39)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlx.show (Unknown Source:2)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd.show (Unknown Source:2)
  at com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity$q0.run (Unknown Source:6)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8107)`enter code here`
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:496)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your app use Firebase Cloud Messaging or Firebase feature?
I found an article that this error was caused by incorrect Firebase SDK versions.

For example, in your gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
```